# Flutter gesturedetector not working in stack widget

Tags: flutter

I am using the `stack` widget to show the back arrow button on an image. And its showing but the problem is it's not tappable mean Gesturededector is not working on Stack.

My code

```
  Stack(
      children: <Widget>[

        Container(
          height: height * 0.4,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(
                'assets/images/place2.jpg',
              ),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          onTap: () => print("first container"),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.03),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: statusBarHeight * 2),

              child: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                size: 25,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: height * 0.3),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(30)),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.05,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: width,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.03),
                        child: Text(
                          'NYC Food Festival',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.03),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.calendar_today,
                              size: 20,
                              color: Color(0xff808080),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: width * 0.02), // give it width
                            Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Sat, May 25, 2020',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xff000000),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 15),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.03),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.attach_money,
                              size: 20,
                              color: Color(0xff808080),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: width * 0.02), // give it width
                            Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  '25,000 PKR',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xff000000),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 15),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: width,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.03),
                        child: Text(
                          'Snaps',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              CarouselSlider(
                                options: CarouselOptions(
                                  autoPlay: true,
                                  aspectRatio: 2.0,
                                  enlargeCenterPage: true,
                                ),
                                items: imageSliders,
                              ),
                            ],
                          )),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: width,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.03),
                        child: Text(
                          'About',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              right: width * 0.03, left: width * 0.03),
                          child: DescriptionTextWidget(
                              text:
                                  "Flutter is Google’s mobile UI framework for crafting high-quality native interfaces on iOS and Android in record time. Flutter works with existing code, is used by developers and organizations around the world, and is free and open source.")
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: width,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.03),
                        child: Text(
                          'Included',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Included(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.01,
                      ),
                      Included(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.01,
                      ),
                      Included(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.01,
                      ),




                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              // color: Color.fromARGB(110, 255, 255, 255),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                topRight: Radius.circular(20),
              ),
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Color.fromARGB(30, 255, 255, 255),
                  Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                ],
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              ),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: InkWell(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 80,
                    vertical: 20,
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    "BOOK NOW",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  return print("Tap");
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

I need to use it as a back button when I navigate but it's not working then for testing I just print a value onTap but its also not working I try to add `behaviour` also.

Comment: Could you please share a complete code of the file where it doesn't work? I injected it into my application and it works. Try rebuilding an application and / or enabling "Pause on All Exceptions" setting in the "Debug" tab to see where it stops. Your code worked for me.

Comment: @kovalyovi uploaded

Comment: You can also use RaisedButton in place of InkWell as it will not show splash as of now but you can see the "Tap" output in Debug Panel. am on mobile so could not post the complete code.

Comment: @Dipesh answered everything right. Just make sure the very last item is the Gesture Detector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you try putting GestureDectector after SingleChildScrollView in a stack.

I guess SingleChildScrollView is lying above GestureDetector since it is a stack.

```
SingleChildScrollView(),
GestureDetector(),
```

Comment: Other Solution didn't work it did. Thanks brother